# Finding the equations of two lines that meet in a point.

Tags: vector-spaces, education

"Give the equations of two lines that meet at the point $(2, -3, 5)$ and which meet at right angles, but do not use that point in either of the equations."

I am having a bad time with this one. I figured out the first line is the vector $(4,-6,10)$, that vector goes through the point, and then I was trying to find a perpendicular vector to $(2,-3,5)$. But if I do the rule of $u \cdot v = 0$, the lines are going to meet at $(0,0,0)$ and I want them to meet at $(2,-3,5)$, an help please?

Comment: A vector doesn't go "through a point" and a line is not the same as a vector.

Comment: Oh, so what can I do?

Comment: I just started the Intersections unit, but according to my notes, there are 3 types, parametric, vector, and symmetric equation. (x-x1)/a = (y-y1)/b = (z-z1)/c

Comment: Like that [x, y, z] = [ax, ay, az] + t[bx, by, bz]

Comment: 2 points in my plane? or 2 lines?

Comment: Ohhhhh, so in that case one of my lines could be, [x, y, z] = [2x, -3y, 5z] + t[bx, by, bz] I don't know the other coordinate, but the "t" should be the one pointing a 90 degree direction from the other line.

Comment: I am sorry, I am really trying. But thanks for taking the time to explain me this, I really appreciate your help, since I am homeschooled I am pretty much on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation of a line is given by $\mathbf r(t) = \mathbf r_0 + t\mathbf v$.  In particular, when our vector space is $\Bbb R^3$, this equation is just $(x,y,z) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + t(v_1, v_2, v_3)$.

Here $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is *any* point on your line, $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is *any* vector *parallel* to your line, and $t$ is your variable.

We know a point that is on both lines, don't we?  It's $(2,-3,5)$.

Basically now all you have to do is find $2$ nonzero vectors which are perpendicular to each other to be the $\mathbf v$'s in your $2$ equations.  I suggest just choosing one randomly and then using the definition of orthogonality to find the other one.

*Definition*: Two vectors, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are orthogonal if and only if $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = \langle \mathbf a, \mathbf b\rangle =0$ (I'm not sure what notation you use for the dot product so I put both of the common ones).

So once you've chosen *any* vector, say $(1,1,1)$, you just need to plug that into this definition to find any other vector orthogonal to it: $(1,1,1)\cdot(a,b,c)=0$.  Just find *any* nonzero solution to this.

Once you have those two vectors you just plug in.  So your two equations will be $(x,y,z) = (2,-3,5) + t(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ and $(x,y,z)=(2,-3,5)+s(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ where $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ and $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ are your two orthogonal (perpendicular) vectors.

However, the question *specifically* asks that you not include the vector $(2,-3,5)$ in your equations.  So basically, you just need one more point on each of these lines to replace the $(2,-3,5)$ with.  So how would you find those two vectors?

Comment: (1,1,1)⋅(1,1,-2)=0 Those can be my vectors.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Can I use a multiple of 2,-3,5? How can I not include that point if that is the point in which my 2 vectors intersect.

Comment: You can't use a multiple of a point unless your two lines happen to go through the origin (and neither one of these do).  How can you find *any* other point on your lines if you already have equations for your lines?

Comment: [x,y,z]=(2,-3,5)+t(1,1,1) and [x,y,z]=(2,-3,5)+s(1,1,-2). Is that valid?

Comment: Or here's another question that might lead you to the solution -- how could you either prove or disprove that the point $(6,2,4)$ is on one of your lines?

Comment: Those are valid equations for your lines, but your problem asks you not to use the point $(2,-3,5)$ in your solutions, so you need to replace that point in both of your equations with $2$ *other* points that happen to be on your lines.  Remember, there are an infinite number of equations which describe these same two lines.

Comment: The multiple of my lines? Like  
[x,y,z]=(1,1,1)+t(2,2,2) and [x,y,z]=(1,1,-2)+t(2,2,-4)

Comment: Try to answer my other question.  How could you prove or disprove that $(6,2,4)$ is a point on the line $(x,y,z)=(2,-3,5)+t(1,1,1)$?

Comment: The collinear equation? See if they are coplanar or collinear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22045/discussion-between-julio-and-bye-world).